# How can I count the files inside a folder of project solution?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, file-io, storage

I want to develop a windows phone based application in which I need to put the number of files in a folder (this folder is already a part of the project) to a list so that at run time I can access those files. If anybody can give me idea of how to do that then it will be great help.

In normal WPF applications we can write code like

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Tempo");
FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
MessageBox.Show(fi.Length.ToString());
```

But Windows phone inside solution how do I do that?

I can get a single file access by this code

```
if (Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/WindowsPhone;component/Folder/file09.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi");
}
```

But inside that folder there are many files and I want to put them into list so at run time I can access those images. But the user won't be knowing about that so it should be a C# code, not a XAML code. Any help would be great.

Comment: sadly in windows phone apps, `Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\images", ". jpg")`      does not work, anyone with a solution for windows phone 8

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy.

Make sure you add the specific folder to the Solution.  Along with any files you want in that folder.

Make sure each file's Properties are set like so:

**Build Action**: Content
**Copy to Output Directory**: Do not copy

---

Make sure the application had loaded before calling

Lets say I had a folder called "Testfiles" and I want to read from it then:

```C#
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReadAllFilesFromFolder("Testfiles");
}

// TODO: recursion to get subfolders and files (maybe?)
public async void ReadAllFilesFromFolder(string folder_name)
{
    var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var assetsFolder = await package.GetFolderAsync(folder_name);
    foreach (var file in await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        // TODO: whatever you want to do with file
        // string filename = file.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although its very late, I have a different way to fulfill my need, but definitely I will give this a try. Thanks